# In pdfbox, why does BufferImage and ImageXObject have different resolution

Tags: java, image, pdf, extract, pdfbox

When I use pdfbox to extract jpeg 2000 image from a book, I found the BufferImage and ImageXObject have different resolution.

The pdf file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yAfTFeAz6bfrcQOAEEm5MFMuPpM-zSa_/view?usp=sharing

code to print resolution

```
    static boolean savePDImage(String name, PDImageXObject image) throws Exception {
        if (null != image && null != image.getImage()) {

            BufferedImage bufferImage = image.getImage();
            String rawSuffix = image.getSuffix().toLowerCase();
            String suffix = image.getSuffix().toLowerCase();
            File imgFile = new File(name + "." + rawSuffix);

            System.out.println(String.format("BufferImage %dx%d, \tImageXObject %dx%d"
                        , bufferImage.getWidth(), bufferImage.getHeight(), image.getWidth(), image.getHeight()));
            return true;
            }
    return false;
    }
```

the console print

```
BufferImage 983x1336,   ImageXObject 983x1336
BufferImage 1965x2672,  ImageXObject 491x668
BufferImage 980x1334,   ImageXObject 980x1334
BufferImage 1959x2668,  ImageXObject 490x667
BufferImage 274x218,    ImageXObject 274x218
BufferImage 98x134,     ImageXObject 98x134
BufferImage 180x224,    ImageXObject 180x224
BufferImage 954x1325,   ImageXObject 954x1325
BufferImage 1914x2659,  ImageXObject 477x662
BufferImage 958x1328,   ImageXObject 958x1328
BufferImage 1923x2665,  ImageXObject 479x664
BufferImage 954x1325,   ImageXObject 954x1325
BufferImage 1914x2659,  ImageXObject 477x662
BufferImage 954x1325,   ImageXObject 954x1325
BufferImage 1914x2659,  ImageXObject 477x662
BufferImage 954x1325,   ImageXObject 954x1325
BufferImage 1914x2659,  ImageXObject 477x662
BufferImage 954x1325,   ImageXObject 954x1325
BufferImage 1914x2659,  ImageXObject 477x662
BufferImage 954x1325,   ImageXObject 954x1325
BufferImage 1914x2659,  ImageXObject 477x662
BufferImage 954x1325,   ImageXObject 954x1325
BufferImage 1914x2659,  ImageXObject 477x662
BufferImage 731x60,     ImageXObject 731x60
BufferImage 954x1325,   ImageXObject 954x1325
BufferImage 1914x2659,  ImageXObject 477x662
BufferImage 954x1325,   ImageXObject 954x1325
```

So why the resolution is different and how to extract the image with ImageXObject resolution?

I think I could use `bufferImage.getScaledInstance( image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)`, but it is not a good idea.

Comment: That's because of the mask that is larger and is evaluated when the BufferedImage is requested. Download PDFDebugger and look at the images, at the first page, go to `Resources/XObject/CL/Mask`.